# Add text to option with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to add "ALL" to an option with the Value of "79" with Javascript or JQuery

```
<select id="locations">    
<option value="79"></option>
</select>
```

End Result should be:

```
<select id="locations">    
<option value="79">ALL</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:

Turns out I also need it done to an checkbox too.

```
<li class=" ">
<label for="ui-multiselect-Location_State-option-14" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
<input id="ui-multiselect-Location_State-option-14" name="multiselect_Location_State" type="checkbox" value="79" title="Maidstone2">
<span></span>
</label>
</li>
```

Again the end result should be:

```
<li class=" ">
<label for="ui-multiselect-Location_State-option-14" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
<input id="ui-multiselect-Location_State-option-14" name="multiselect_Location_State" type="checkbox" value="79" title="Maidstone2">
<span>ALL</span>
</label>
</li>
```

The value is still "79" however the code for the first option didnt work on it.

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the element using [`attribute selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and set the text using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method as follows:

```js
$('option[value="79"]').text("ALL");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="locations">
  <option value="79"></option>
</select>
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('option[value="79"]').textContent = "ALL";
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you! Will Answer when the timer allows me :)

Comment: Updated my question to include something i just discovered any chance you can help with that one too?

Comment: @user3516568 try `$(':checkbox[value="79"]').next().text("ALL");`

Comment: Didnt work, So i just re-coded it to a normal option instead of a multi-option checkbox.

Thanks alot! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[attribute-equals-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
$('option[value=79]').text('ALL');
```